# Is there a faster way for finding the circumference of a shape?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, scipy

I have an image showing some objects, where one object is always inside the other.
The background is always black.

[image]

I want to know the circumference of both objects and got to a solution.
I use a filterkernel to get the 4-neighborhood of each pixel. Then I count the number of zero pixels around the pixel. This gives me the length in pixel units of the shape. I count only in the case, if the center pixel is the desired color.

```
from scipy import misc, ndimage
import numpy as np
import time

def get_circumference(arr, only=50, repl=50):
    def c_length(values):
        # 3rd value is the pixel
        if values[2] == only:
            return sum([x == 0 or (repl == 0 and x != only) for x in values[[0,1,3,4]]])
        return 0

    fp = np.array([[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0]])
    res = ndimage.generic_filter(arr, c_length, footprint=fp)

    return np.sum(res, axis=None)

x = ndimage.imread("image.png", mode='L')

tic = time.time()
inner = get_circumference(x, only=255, repl=0)
outer = get_circumference(x, only=128, repl=128)
print("Inner object: {}, outer object: {}, took: {}".format(inner, outer, time.time() - tic))
```

gives me:

```
Inner object: 510, outer object: 1054, took: 0.8387038707733154
```

It works quite fine. But it is very slow.
It takes about 500 to 1000 ms for a single image.
As I need to do this for several thousand images, it will take too much time.

Is there any way to speed this up? I know, that the images will always contain three colors and that the inner section will always fully enclosed by the outer one. Also there will never be the case of an shape crossing image boundaries.

Of course there are different methods to actually calculate the circumference.
Given just a single pixel, there are two possible solutions: 1 or 4.
The first method just counts the number of pixels, i.e. a single pixel counts as a single unit of circumfernece. In the latter case, the actual edges of the pixel are counted.
In my solution I used the latter method to count the circumfernece.
If you count just by edge detection and histogram, you will get the first solution.

Here is another example, where this difference can actually be caculated by hand as well:
[image: extreme case example]

It consists of 8 grey pixels and one white pixel.
The outer circumfernece is therefore 3+3+3+3 = 12 and the inner is 4.
Pixel counting by histogram would give instead 8 for the outer and 1 for the inner.

Comment: Cool question! Do you have your *"correct answers"* for the given image for verification purposes please? Is the image representative in terms of size and format? Can you provide one or two other sample images - also with your correct answers, please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I updated the method of counting and also added another example (a very extreme case)

Comment: What's the correct answer for the large image please?

Answer (score 3):

I use `OpenCV` for image processing, and `this question` is not that hard for `OpenCV`.

> 1. Read the image and convert to gray
> 2. Threshold the gray
> 3. Find contours on the threshed binary image.
> 4. Calculate arclen(circumference) and area(if need) for each contour.

---

Threshold with 120:

[image]

```
Th: 120.0
Length: 869.578
Area: 53932.000
Time: 0.002293109893798828s
```

---

Threshold with 200:

[image]

```
Th: 200.0
Length: 423.990
Area: 11892.000
Time: 0.0015425682067871094s
```

---

```
## -------------------------------------
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2018.01.16 10:23:47 CST
# 2018.01.16 12:30:20 CST
"""
Env: Python 3.5 + OpenCV 3.3
"""
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

def findArc(img, th):
    res = img.copy()
    print("Th: {}".format(th))

    ts = time.time()
    ## convert to gray 
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    ## threshold the gray 
    th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, th, 255,  cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    ## Find contours on the binary threshed image 
    cnts = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]

    ## calcualte 
    for cnt in cnts:
        arclen = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        cv2.drawContours(res, [cnt], -1, (0,255,0), 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
        print("Length: {:.3f}\nArea: {:.3f}".format(arclen, area))

    print("Time: {}s".format(time.time()-ts))

    cv2.imshow("res", res)
    cv2.waitKey();cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    cv2.imwrite("res_{}.png".format(th), res)


img = cv2.imread("img03.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

findArc(img, 120)
findArc(img, 200)
```

Comment: Your solution looks fine and obviously faster, but the calculation for the circumference is different. But I know that there are several ways to calculate the circumfernece of an pixelated object.

Comment: One can't really calculate the exact circumference value of a circle in an image.  So as in those ellipses. Accumulated error must exist. And after do approximation for contour, the values maybe the close.

Answer (score 1):

You can address this by using a morphological erosion, which will change the color of the pixels having a lower neighbor. Then comparing the two images for equality you get the result below.

These operations should be available in OpenCV and run much faster than Python code.

[image]

Also note that counting the pixels of a given color is just the computation of the histogram.

---

**Update:**

We have even easier:

- take the histogram,
- erode,
- take the histogram again.

The difference between the counts is the number of outline pixels. And you get the counts for gray and white in a single go.

With my super-duper optimized functions

```
Histogram: 0.250 ms
Erosion:   0.050 ms
Histogram: 0.250 ms
Total:     0.550 ms
```

Even better:

Take the average of the image and its erosion, then histogram. The outline pixels appear with intermediate gray values.

```
Erosion:   0.060 ms
Average:   0.020 ms
Histogram: 0.230 ms
Total:     0.310 ms
```

Now the bottleneck is the reading of the image (from a file).

Answer (score 0):

If you use [contour detection](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html), it is possible to detect the circumference of both objects at the same time for the given image. This gets a bit tricky if the image is natural, but that will be the case for other methods such as region and morphology based methods.